# How to test an application without any specification?

Tags: exploratory

I have to test an application which does not have any specification or user manual. It has evolved over a period of time and there are no similar products in the market yet. I know exploratory testing is the way to go but where do I start?

Comment: Do you know that application flow and everything?

Comment: @HelpingHands why would I ask this question if I knew everything?

Comment: I knew but without getting familier application flow , testing will be meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

- Get familiar with the application by using it.
- Try to get an overview and notice the different areas / components you recognize.
- Use the application from a user point of view.
- A lot of questions will come up in your mind. Write them down and clarify them later with business analysts and developers.

Aks the following questions:

- What type of users use our application?
- How many users we have?
- What technology is behind the application? (Programming Language, Services, Dependencies, Hardware etc.)
- Which browser, operating system and so on is supported?
- Which features are the most important ones?

Create a page in your intranet Wiki or something similar to notice each single information you get. On this way you can take a look there, if you forget something and you can give it to other people that are new in the compony.

I am sure that this list is not nearly complete. But I hope it will help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My advice; Get hold of an actual USER.

Do whatever it takes, wine, dine, open doors, knock on doors etc. Just get hold of an user and use time with him/her.

Your goal should be to try to understand what problems the application is supposed to solve and how these problems are solved today.

Also in addition you might just accidentaly get a representative for your reference user group...

Answer (score 0):

1. At first review this Application Properly.
2. Then create test scenario and Risk Management.
3. If any problem about Application's any functionality, then communicate with Client and Project Manager.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by review application properly? Can you elaborate more how to create test scenario without any expected results formally defined?

Comment: How would I review without knowing what the application is supposed to do?

Comment: Before use of Android Phone, any user not read their documentation book. User just use it and learn about any option functionality.